# Background on a deleted answer is partially white on mobile theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, deleted-answers

Deleted answer and its comments have red-ish background color.

However, in the mobile theme, it's still partially white:

> [image]

As you can see, the area around voting arrows, both of the post and the comment(s) is still white.

[Link to the deleted answer for easier reproduction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129045/152859).

Chrome latest version, both on mobile device and desktop device using mobile theme.

Comment: @Paweł Congrats on your diamond! No more shame in suggesting edits that [might get rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44234), lol... does the latest change fix this bug? Edit: just checked, it does! Can you please post some quick answer to get the reputation you deserve, and change the status to completed? :)

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, this should be fixed now.